# Different behavior figure and colorbar axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a bit confused by the different behavior of the figure and colorbar axes. A small example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

pl.figure()
ax = pl.subplot()
pl.imshow(np.random.random(16).reshape(4,4))
cb = pl.colorbar()

# Remove left spine, and move bottom one outward:
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 5))

# Now, do the same for the colorbar ?!
cb.ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
cb.ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 5))
```

[image]

`ax` and `cb.ax` are both a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` instance, but the axes behave different when I try to modify them. How can I modify the colorbar axes similar to how I changed the main figure?